# Matlab: Error when loading trained classification model from folder and using predictFcn command

Tags: matlab

i'm trying to save and load a trained model from the classification learner app so i don't have to export it over and over again. When using the command predictFcn to predict the labels this error occurs:

Unrecognized field name "predictFcn".

Error in Predictpgrm (line 166)

YPred(i,1) = trainedModel15m.predictFcn(XTrain_test(i,:));

This errod only occurs when i'm trying to save and then load the model into the workspace.
Is there another way of saving a trained model from the classification learner app? Or is something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I needed to save the model as a struct. Why doesn't Matlab do this as default?
Anyways...

The new saving command looks like this:

save('TrainedModel.mat','-struct','trainedModel')

After that you can load the struct in as ususal.

Hope this helps anyone.